# iOS Wrong UITableView size

Tags: ios, size, uitableview

I am building an iPad application, and I added a simple UITableView to an inner view, somewhere in a XIB file.

The problem is, as you can see in the image, the UITableView doesn't have the right size. Of course, I set it in IB (should be 360x243, as I recall), but no matter what I do, it still shows up wrong. If I increase the size to, let's say 600 pixels width, it displays OK, but, then, it'll be a little hack-ish and will be a nightmare to maintain.

Does anybody here have an explanation to this behavior?

---

I don't have enough reputation, so here is the link to the image : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/screenshot20111002at413.png/

*On the image, the UITableView background is set to white to be able to see it.*

Comment: please explain the expected look.. we can see how your views look at the moment but you didn't explain how you want them to be arranged / sized

Comment: Have you tried to delete the app from the device/simulator and re-install it? Maybe it's an old version of the XIB file that causes the problem.

Comment: ChristianK: Tried that, didn't work...

Comment: Martin: Well, it should be aligned like http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/screenshot20111002at834.png/. (This image is a simple screenshot of the interface builder, which actually displays the right UITableView size)

Comment: did you set any autoresizing masks in IB?

Comment: You're a life savior! Can't believe it was so simple. Actually, the autosizing was on for every direction. I think it just messed with everything... Now, it's only on for top and left, and it works like a charm!

Comment: Btw, I'm kind of new here, do I need to post an answer, even if I don't know what really happened for this to get messed up?

Comment: i just created the answer :P you could accept it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your autoresizing masks. Those can mess up view structures easily.